# Construct a HTML table with irregular Multilavel Header

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table, header, multi-level

I would like to construct a table as follows:

```
|   Major Heading 1   |   Major Heading 2   |   Major Heading 3   |  Major Heading 4 |
|                     |  Minor1  |  Minor2  |  Minor1  |  Minor2  |                  |  more similar headers ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1   |   col2   |   col3   |   col4   |   col1   |   col2   |   col3  |  col4  |
rest of table ...
```

There are two types of header, one with sub-header and one only single. I have tried, single header with rowspan and colspan is 2. For the multilevel, main header will have rowspan 1 and colspan 2 and for sub-header it will colspan 1 and rowspan 1.

I have also tried with adding nester  after multilevel header . But it's breaking the table. Can anyone give me some idea to to construct the table using html only without any css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I figured out for this requirement is to maintain two row `<tr>` for Header and Subheader. And,

- All Headers should have equal `colspan="2"` (double of Subheader colspan),
- Headers without Subheader will have `rowspan="2"` (double of Header with Subheader and it's rowspan)
- Headers with Subheader will have `rowspan="1"` (equal of Subheader rowspan)
- Subheaders have to follow the order of respective Headers

Working example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            td,
            th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Head 1</th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">Head 2</th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Head 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="1">Subhead 2.1</th>
                <th rowspan="1">Subhead 2.2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Col 1</td>
                <td>Col 2</td>
                <td>Col 3</td>
                <td>Col 4</td>
                <td>Col 5</td>
                <td>Col 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```